# Zoom image doesn't work in rtl language

Tags: jquery, html

[image: look like this]
I am working with gallery page images .

The zoom images work normally when I add  LTR direction but the problem is when I add `dir="rtl"` to the HTML tag.

The zoom is not working:

```
<!-- gallery -->
    <section >
    <div  class="container gallery-container">
    <h1> Gallery</h1>
    <p class="page-description text-center">Grid  Zoom </p>
    <div dir="ltr" class="tz-gallery" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a class="lightbox" href="../images/park.jpg">
                    <img src="../images/park.jpg" alt="Park">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a class="lightbox" href="../images/bridge.jpg">
                    <img src="../images/bridge.jpg" alt="Bridge">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                <a class="lightbox" href="../images/tunnel.jpg">
                    <img src="../images/tunnel.jpg" alt="Tunnel">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a class="lightbox" href="../images/coast.jpg">
                    <img src="../images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
    </section>
<script src="js/gallery/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
<script>
    baguetteBox.run('.tz-gallery');
</script>
```

Comment: When you say it is not working what specifically is not working about it? Is the behavior wrong, if so state the desired behavior and the incorrect behavior. Are there error messages in the console?

Comment: the zoom not displaying images  (look at image in top ) .no no errors in console the problem is indir="rtl" because i working with arabic language